BlockingNotAllowedException in Quarkus application when reading from InputStream
I'm developing a Java application using Quarkus 3.8.6.redhat-00005. In one of my classes, I'm trying to read from the InputStream of the ContainerRequestContext while filtering requests. Here's the code:
package br.com.bb.t99.rest;
import io.smallrye.common.annotation.Blocking;
import io.vertx.core.Future;
import io.vertx.core.buffer.Buffer;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerRequest;
import jakarta.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import jakarta.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import jakarta.ws.rs.container.PreMatching;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Context;
import jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import java.io.IOException;
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class TesteFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Context
    HttpServerRequest request;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
        containerRequestContext.getEntityStream().readAllBytes();
        //TODO: Edit the request body 
    }
}

When I try to run this, I get a BlockingNotAllowedException with the message Attempting a blocking read on io thread. The full error message is:
org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.BlockingNotAllowedException: Attempting a blocking read on io thread
19:34:45 ERROR [br.co.bb.de.er.re.fi.ExceptionFilter] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1)  Resp {statusCode=500, body={errors=[{code=ERRO_SISTEMA, message=Erro na execu??o da solicita??o., variaveisMonitoradas={ORIGEM-ERRO=br.com.bb.t99.rest.TesteFilter - linha: 25., MOTIVO-ERRO=org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.BlockingNotAllowedException: Attempting a blocking read on io thread, ID-REQUISICAO=347f2608-7f8e-447a-8b35-39d08c8a32f5}}]}}: org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.BlockingNotAllowedException: Attempting a blocking read on io thread
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.VertxInputStream$VertxBlockingInput.readBlocking(VertxInputStream.java:245)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.VertxInputStream.readIntoBuffer(VertxInputStream.java:123)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.VertxInputStream.read(VertxInputStream.java:85)
        at java.base/java.io.InputStream.readNBytes(InputStream.java:412)
        at java.base/java.io.InputStream.readAllBytes(InputStream.java:349)
        at br.com.bb.t99.rest.TesteFilter.filter(TesteFilter.java:25)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.ResourceRequestFilterHandler.handle(ResourceRequestFilterHandler.java:48)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:131)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:147)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.RestInitialHandler.beginProcessing(RestInitialHandler.java:48)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.handle(ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.java:23)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.handle(ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.java:10)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1285)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:177)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:137)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.options.HttpServerCommonHandlers$1.handle(HttpServerCommonHandlers.java:62)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.options.HttpServerCommonHandlers$1.handle(HttpServerCommonHandlers.java:40)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1285)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:177)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:137)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.ResteasyReactiveRecorder$13.handle(ResteasyReactiveRecorder.java:339)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.ResteasyReactiveRecorder$13.handle(ResteasyReactiveRecorder.java:332)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1285)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:177)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:137)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.handleHotReplacementRequest(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:133)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$5.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:415)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$5.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:411)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1285)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:177)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:137)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouterImpl.handle(RouterImpl.java:68)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouterImpl.handle(RouterImpl.java:37)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.options.HttpServerCommonHandlers$2.handle(HttpServerCommonHandlers.java:86)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.options.HttpServerCommonHandlers$2.handle(HttpServerCommonHandlers.java:69)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$1.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:147)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$1.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:123)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup$4.handle(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:190)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup$4.handle(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:181)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl$4.onSuccess(FutureImpl.java:176)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.lambda$emitSuccess$0(FutureBase.java:60)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:173)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:166)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)


19:34:45 ERROR [or.jb.re.re.se.co.RuntimeExceptionMapper] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1)  A blocking operation occurred on the IO thread. This likely means you need to use the @io.smallrye.common.annotation.Blocking annotation on the Resource method, class or jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application class.

--
2 tests failed (11 passing, 0 skipped), 2 tests were run in 1737078ms. Tests completed at 19:34:18 due to changes to TesteFilter.class.
Press [e] to edit command line args (currently ''), [r] to re-run, [o] Toggle test output, [:] for the terminal, [h] for more options>

I don't fully understand why this is happening. Is there a preferred way to read and edit the request body in a non-blocking way in Quarkus? How can solve this issue? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
I have already tried add the @io.smallrye.common.annotation.Blocking annotation to the endpoint, a class that extends jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application, and the filter itself. However, all these attempts were unsuccessful in resolving the problem.

What you are trying to do won't work in a @PreMatching filter

Is there any alternative way to do the same with rest reactive?

Not really to be honest. Why exactly do you need to entire body?

Just three things need to be done: replace invalid characters with spaces, add the content type, and if the body is null, replace it with a default object. I understand that these tasks are typically handled on the client side. However, the teams responsible for this application don't have control over the client. Therefore, it's necessary to address these issues in the filter. I'm considering creating something like a BFF (Backend for Frontend) to handle these requests before they reach the Quarkus application.

Couldn't it be done by an API gateway? Or even a simple Camel route that is in front of the application?

The approach you're using is causing this error because, when using the @PreMatching filter, it is expected that the actions are non-blocking, since the event loop is always used for these operations. The operation of reading the InputStream within the ContainerRequestContext is blocking, and since it is executed in the event loop, the org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.BlockingNotAllowedException is thrown.
Considering the exception being thrown and the purpose of the filter you mentioned in a previous comment, I believe a possible solution to the problem is as follows:

Remove the @PreMatching annotation from the class.
Use the @ServerRequestFilter annotation directly on the method (without passing attributes, to use the default configuration). This will ensure that the method is called before the request reaches the endpoint, and its operations will be executed in a non-blocking manner (executed in a worker thread).
Remove the implementation of the ContainerRequestFilter interface. This is important because using @ServerRequestFilter in a class that implements this interface causes the method to be executed twice before reaching the endpoint.

package com.example;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.ServerRequestFilter;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerRequest;
import jakarta.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import jakarta.ws.rs.container.PreMatching;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Context;
import jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class TesteFilter {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(TesteFilter.class.getName());

    @Context
    HttpServerRequest request;

    @ServerRequestFilter
    public void doFilter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.info("Intercepting the request in the Filter");

        String body = new String(containerRequestContext.getEntityStream().readAllBytes());
        LOGGER.info("Original request body: " + body);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Language language = mapper.readValue(body, Language.class);
        
        String modifiedBody = mapper.writeValueAsString(
                new Language("Modified-" + language.getType(),
                             "Modified-" + language.getName()
                            ));
        LOGGER.info("Modified request body: " + modifiedBody);

        containerRequestContext.setEntityStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(modifiedBody.getBytes()));
    }
}

Here’s the Quarkus documentation covering this topic:
Request or response filters - Quarkus Documentation
Lastly, but no less important, you mention that you're using Quarkus version 3.8.6.redhat-00005, which leads me to believe that you already have a subscription to the Red Hat Build of Quarkus. Don’t hesitate to open a support ticket with Red Hat to get help with issues like this.
